# Create .c-files and .h-files

Tags: atmel

How do I create simple .c-files and .h-files in Atmel studio? I know that this is a really simple question but that is kind of the problem, al questions regarding this topic seems to be special cases and exceptions. This is just concerning ordinary files. I have a few files that is included but I need to add a few more files.

Answer (score 0):

Use File -> New (or Ctl+N) to bring up the new file dialog. From there you should be able to select "C/C++" from the Installed templates area on the left to then select "C File" for a blank .C file or "Include File" for a blank .H file.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be part of the project. In fact, I don't know where that new-created file ended up. If it was created at all.